# change volume of a youtube video while playing

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

When i play a Youtube video like this:

https://www.youtube.com/tv?#/watch/video/control?v=d1-VK12FZhs&resume&t=0m4s

i need to change the volume injecting javascript.

I know the API has the function

```
player.setVolume(volume:Number):Void
```

as i use this for get the currentTime:

```
document.querySelector('.video-stream').getCurrentTime();
```

i have tried with

```
document.querySelector('.video-stream').setVolume(20);
```

but i got an error telling "setVolume is not a function"

How to use it for change the volume with the video playing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey Peter what have you tried so far?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We don't have enough to reproduce the experience here :(

Comment: i have updated the description. thanks in advance

Comment: If you `console.log(document.querySelector('.video-stream'))` do you get any of the object's properties in the console?

Comment: i get this: <video tabindex="-1" class="video-stream html5-main-video" controlslist="nodownload" src="blob:https://www.youtube.com/15da9225-d0e1-4485-99c3-b638dab88c9a" style="width: 725px; height: 408px; left: 0px; top: 160.094px;"></video>

Comment: the error i get is: Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).setVolume is not a function    at <anonymous>:1:41

Comment: yes, i get list of properties, but setVolume is not present...

Comment: Edit: If you try to adjust the DOM element's attributes using functions not attached to that object's prototype it will not work.  It looks like this is a case of the YouTube Library not being attached to the DOM element you are trying to adjust.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like that:

```
var vid = document.querySelector('.video-stream');
vid.volume = 0.1; // where 0 - no volume and 1 - 100% of volume. So 0.1 is 10% of volume. It works for me.
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution by [Dead Sky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62945499/868860) works, but on ***live streams*** the volume falls back to the previous (set by moving the slider or by pressing the shortcut) value after a couple of seconds. So I tried the following combination:

```js
document.querySelector(".html5-video-player").setVolume(50);
```

Now the volume doesn't fall back and is also synchronized with the player interface (the slider value).

Comment: It really works, really helped me when studying. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I assume here that you are looking at the example listed [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo):

They are using an iFrame to control the video.  You won't be able to access the object directly using the querySelector since it is not native to your DOM.  You'll need to use their API properly by [following their docs.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Example_Video_Player_Constructors)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="range" id="volumeChnage" min="0" max="100" step="10">
<a href="https://linkinblink.enally.in target="_blank">Link In Blink</a>
<script>
document.getElementById('volumeChnage').addEventListener('change', function() {
    const volume = this.value;
    console.log("volume:", volume);
    player.setVolume(volume);
});

// This is working fine for me.
// Output https://linkinblink.enally.in 
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).